# Google play published apk and obb but need user to download only apk

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

My game 160MB of size, I separate it one `apk` and one `main OBB`, the question is, is it possible if publish it together but need user download only apk, it will download `obb` in the game later? The point is made it look smallest size of the game for download in google play and using google play server  host instead of using our host.

Comment: Use Google apk expansion library http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: I have confuse, upload apk and obb together to google play, how to force user download only apk?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#DownloadProcess), *`If Google Play is able to download the expansion files (which is the case for most devices), it downloads them along with the APK. If Google Play is unable to download the expansion files, it downloads the APK only`.*

When the user launches your application, *`your app must check whether the expansion files are already saved on the device. If yes, your app is ready to go. If no, your app must download the expansion files over HTTP from Google Play`.*

So Google Play will always try to download the expansion file(s) at the same time if downloads the APK, so your application has everything it needs when the user opens it for the first time. Unless there is no available space to save the expansion file(s), or no network connection. So, no way to force users to download the APK only in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

As @ztan said, in the worst case need to publish only apk file and download obb in the first time from our host.